# Stack Overflow: trouble logging in with Firefox

Tags: support, firefox, windows-7

When I connect to Stack Overflow and click on the "login" button, I am taken to the login page, as expected. When I click on "Google" (as I always have), the "Welcome back, Number8, you are being logged in ..." popup appears briefly, then disappears, and I'm not logged in...

Is there a known issue with Firefox, or a configuration setting I haven't figured out yet?

Bonus: I can't seem to post a question on this site from Firefox (I'm using Internet Explorer 10 to post this).

Platform: Windows 7, FireFox 21.0.

Comment: Sounds like a Firefox cookie configuration problem.

Comment: I cannot confirm that. It works for me like expected.

Comment: Weird.  I can now log in to meta.StackOverflow.com, StackOverflow.com, SuperUser.com....
Not sure what changed ?!

Comment: Seems like clearing all history in Firefox has cleared up the problem (at least for now).

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: JFMiller: I am logged in w/ Firefox now, although it initially appeared that I wasn't -- confusing.  (I generally use my Google credentials.)  Clearing the Firefox cache as thoroughly as possible is, I think, what made the difference.

Comment: Same here, clearing cache also fixed it for meta, but the problem persists with stackoverflow itself.

Comment: I just connected on this meta but I have that problem on RPG.stackexchange tho